# <main>: uninitialized constant Msf (NameError)

Tags: ruby, metasploit

I'm getting an error while running a ruby script. Even though I've downloaded and installed Metasploit.

```
`<main>': uninitialized constant Msf (NameError)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Metasploit exploits need to be run through metasploit to have the correct environment (more than just a simple external ruby process provides). Usually, you would run the though `msfconsole` or `msfcli`. Refer to the [metasploit documentation](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/msfconsole/) for details.